# PHP - select ONLY file in folder without foreach()?

Tags: php

I have a script that places a CSV file into a temporary folder where it will remain until another script picks it up for import into my DB. This is a separated script and for various reasons cannot do both the placement into the temp folder AND the consecutive database import.

Since I now have a separated import script, I first need to scan the temp folder and look for the import-file, which is the ONLY file in the folder anyway, but has a constantly changing filename that I cannot pre-define. My question now is, how can I get the filename of said file, assign it to a variable and use this later for the database import?

When using a `foreach()` loop I end up with an array, but rather would like a string for further usage.

PHP

```
if(file_exists('./'.$temp)) {
    $files = scandir('./'.$temp.'/');

    foreach ($files as $attachment) {
        if (in_array($attachment, array(".",".."))) continue;

        $import_file = $attachment;
    }
} else {
    die("Temp Folder for $temp could not be found, hence no files exist for import. Operation cancelled.");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `scandir` is ordered alphabetically (http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php), you file will always be at the end of the `scandir` array (on non-unix systems it is the only file, on unix systems it comes after `.` and `..`).

Thus, you just need to get the last item of the array, like so:

```
$s = scandir("./".$temp."/");
$import_file = $s[count($s)-1];
```

This code automatically retrieves the name of the third file in the `temp` folder, so as long as there are **no** other files in there it should work perfectly.

Comment: Its a nice idea, but `.` and `..` is only present on UNIX servers (AFAIK), so what if this script were to run on non-Unix machines? Also, when running the code I get a `Undefined offset: 2` error.

Comment: still getting a `Undefined offset: 0` error. Does `scandir` really support that format?

Comment: @Armitage2k Is there a file in the temp folder? It won't work if there's not. You can put an `@` sign at the start of the line to silence these errors if that's the case.

Comment: @Armitage2k Whoa, my bad. That code didn't work, I forgot that `preg_grep` kept the original indexes. My latest edit works, trust me :D